# How to get to the next iteration in a function that ads up Divisors

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on this for a while and I've just met the condition of not including the number itself in the addition. but it seems to notwant to get passed 3. is it my logic? And why does this list keep returning as None?

Any assistance would be appreciated

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  div = 1
  total = []
  while (n % div) == 0:
    if n == 0:
      return 0
    if (n % div) == 0: 
        n = int(n / div) 
        total.append(div) 
        total.append(n)
        if div == 1:
          total.remove(n)
        div += 1 
        print(total) #this is to check if the list is working (it's not)
    else:
      return sum(total)
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
#print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

Answer (score 0):

try the placeholder: `"hello %s what would you like to do?" % name`... hope this helps. More on placeholders: [Placeholders in Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html).